# Aggregate multiple properties of a class into a string

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Employee {
  string Name { get; set;}
  string Title { get; set;}
}
```

From this I want to construct a string which contains the name and title of every employee.  Easy enough with a for loop, but I'd like to use the LINQ Aggregate method if possible.

Something like:

```
char delim = ',';

string theList = employees.Aggregate((x, y) => $"[{x.Title}] {x.Name}" + delim + y);
```

What I'm struggling with is how to construct it.

Is there a way to make this happen or should I just fall back to a foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `String.Join`?

```
string theList = string.Join(",", employees.Select(x => $"[{x.Title}] {x.Name}"));
```

We represent each `employee` in required format:

```
employees.Select(x => $"[{x.Title}] {x.Name}")
```

and then `Join` all these representations into single string using `","` as a delimiter.

Comment: Bingo, worked perfect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It’s very simple.

```
var theList = employees.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1.Title + ", " + s2.Name);
```